# Html Buttons Piling

Tags: html, button

I have two buttons, they look like this

```
<button class="Entery-Buttons">c#</button>
<button class="Entery-Buttons">Html</button>
```

And they piled (Meaning they were on top of each Other), so I tried adding this to the class

```
.Entery-Buttons{Margin-left:20px;}
```

And the buttons still sticked together.

```css
.Entery-Buttons
{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<button class="Entery-Buttons">c#</button>
    <button class="Entery-Buttons">Html</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them into a container and apply position style to the container:

```css
.Entery-Buttons
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.Entery-Buttons > button
{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<span class="Entery-Buttons">
  <button>c#</button>
  <button>Html</button>
</span>
```